# Python throws strange KeyError when running from Jenkins buildbot

Tags: python, permissions, jenkins

I have a python script that I can run successfully as the jenkins user on a machine. When I use the jenkins web front-end to configure a job to run on the machine, I give it the python script as the job to run. For some reason, I get the strangest KeyError that makes no sense to me in the context of Python, so perhaps someone out there has seen this kind of thing before:

```
    log_name = '-'.join([status_map[test.status], test.config[0], test.config[1], test.group_raw+'.'+test.title])+'.log'
KeyError: 'error: failed to open driver pseudo terminal : Device not configuredFAILURE'
```

The 'FAILURE' that's appended to the end of the error message is actually the value of test.status which is being looked up in status_map in the line where this error gets thrown. But, as far as I can tell the code is sound, there should be no error, and when I run it myself through the command line the script runs fine. What could the problem be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a variable named `test.status` whose value is `error: failed to open driver pseudo terminal : Device not configuredFAILURE`

But the dict `status_map` does not contain any such key, hence accesing this dict with test.status key causes the keyError.

```
status_map[test.status]

KeyError: 'error: failed to open driver pseudo terminal : Device not configuredFAILURE'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
log_name = '-'.join([status_map[test.status], test.config[0], test.config[1], test.group_raw+'.'+test.title])+'.log'
KeyError: 'error: failed to open driver pseudo terminal : Device not configuredFAILURE'
```

You need to check first **key** of dict exist or not, First Check **test.status** key whether exist in **status_map** using **status_map.has_key(test.status)**

```
if status_map.has_key(test.status):
    log_name = '-'.join([status_map[test.status], test.config[0], test.config[1], str(test.group_raw)+'.'+test.title])+'.log'
```